# How can I transfer the information I get from the form to another page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, backend

How can I show the information I got from the place where I entered the title and text on the announcement page?

repo:https://github.com/qswezy/spa1

We have added the form and we want to show it in the announcements

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Also it is not a best practice to use a zip file in a github repo. That makes it pretty hard to track changes between commits.

Answer (score 0):

Forms usually have target page. So, this is the page that will receive your submitted data, usually in some type of POST array (if you submitted it as a post.) If this assumes JavaScript, you probably need to run an Express server to do this.